# ng enter and ng leave animations not working with ion-view

Tags: ionic-framework

How do I get `ng-enter` and `ng-leave` animations to work in ion-view?

```
<ion-view class="kitchenmenu"></ion-view>
```

CSS:

```
.kitchenmenu{background:yellow}

.kitchenmenu.ng-leave      {
  -webkit-animation: animated slideInDown 0.5s both ease-in;
  -moz-animation:animated slideInDown 0.5s both ease-in;
  animation: animated slideInDown 0.5s both ease-in;
}
.kitchenmenu.ng-enter    { 
  -webkit-animation:animated slideInUp 0.5s both ease-in;
  -moz-animation:animated slideInUp 0.5s both ease-in;
  animation:animated slideInUp 0.5s both ease-in;  
}
```

The above however does not work. I tried adding ng-view directive to it as well but no help.